# Do not insert null fields of a form in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, frameworks, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I have a form in symfony that works perfectly. If I fill all the fields 
But if any of them they empty, it gives me an error when they will insert to the database because they can't insert null fields.
The error is: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'foto' cannot be null 
The fields in this table are configured like Null=no
If I perform an INSERT, from the console, indicating the fields that are filled, inserts them correctly.
Does anyone know how I can do to just insert into the database those fields that have been filled out in symfony?

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: This should be moved to [Spanish Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Voting to close as unclear, because it is not written in English and this is an English language site.

Comment: This post using spanish language, so, it need move to Spanish Stackoverflow

Comment: ok sorry I move it

Comment: I presume the form is using an underlying entity. You have to set the `foto` property as nullable. Assuming that you are using Doctrine annotations, this is something like `@ORM\Column(name="foto", nullable=true)`. If you post your entity code that will help us because we won't have to guess.

Comment: /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="foto", type="blob", length=16777215, nullable=true)
     */
    private $foto="";

Comment: that is not working anymore in SF 6.3 - Attributes of nullable fields are ignored by validator - you need set option in EntityFormType "is_required" => false

Answer (score 0):

You should either fill that `Not Nullable` field with actual data, fill it with some kind of default data or change your form so that this field does not come to your controller as `Null`.